# Removing dotted border around selected JList items

Tags: java, swing, border, jlist

The Swing component JList using the system LaF has a dotted border around the currently selected or focused item.

Is there a way to remove borders from selected items entirely?

Comment: The focus rectangle is supplied by the default cell renderer. You could implement your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many look-and-feels you can simple remove the focus border by setting the following UI property:

```
UIManager.put("List.focusCellHighlightBorder", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```